# SSH with GSSAPITrustDns in Arch

Tags: ssh, arch-linux, openssh, kerberos

I am trying to set-up my computer to ssh without a password to a remote server. I am following [these instructions](https://linux.web.cern.ch/docs/kerberos-access/), but I am having a problem:

I can successfully run

```
kinit -f afsusername@CERN.CH
```

and I see the Kerberos ticket with

```
klist -f
```

It expires in 1 day, but it is there (will I have to renew this once a day? That is a problem for my future self).

The current problem is with the `~/.ssh/config` file:

```
HOST lxplus*
    GSSAPITrustDns yes
    GSSAPIAuthentication yes
    GSSAPIDelegateCredentials yes
```

I get an error:

```
/home/me/.ssh/config: line 6: Bad configuration option: gssapitrustdns
/home/me/.ssh/config: terminating, 1 bad configuration options
```

So apparently this `GSSAPITrustDns` is not available.

I am running:

```
[me@frankenstein ~]$ uname -srm
Linux 5.17.1-arch1-1 x86_64
```

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 2):

I managed to solve this by adding the following to my `/etc/krb5.conf` file:

```
[libdefaults]
    rdns = false
```

It would be good if somebody could provide an explanation of why this works, or if there is a better fix.

Answer (score 0):

> So apparently this `GSSAPITrustDns` is not available.

Several GSSAPI options including `GSSAPITrustDns` are not actually part of standard OpenSSH – they are added by downstream patches, so they are only available in Debian/Ubuntu (and perhaps Fedora/RHEL), whereas Arch keeps its OpenSSH patching to a minimum.

As far as I know, `GSSAPITrustDns` is more or less equivalent to `[libdefaults] rdns =`, and in any case rDNS usage is *enabled* by default in current MIT Krb5 versions. I think the CERN documentation only asks you to enable this option for SSH because they're *disabling* `rdns` in their global /etc/krb5.conf. (I guess it kind of makes sense because they're using AD Kerberos?)

Note that your first example (SSH option) *enables* rDNS usage, while your own answer *disables* it, which seems to me like it's **the opposite of what you tried to achieve** and I'm not really sure what makes you say "this works".

> It expires in 1 day, but it is there (will I have to renew this once a day? That is a problem for my future self).

That's normal for Kerberos tickets. By default, you will indeed have to `kinit` again once a day.

Typically you can use `kinit -r 7d` to get a ticket that can be *renewed* for up to 7 days without a password (exchanging the old ticket for a new one) simply by running `kinit -R`. Note that your realm administrator might have adjusted the possible renewal time – if it's shorter or disabled, the KDC will just quietly cap the renewal time to the maximum allowed, so check `klist` afterwards.

The `krenew` tool (found in the AUR "[kstart](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/kstart)" package) can be used to refresh tickets in background, as a somewhat smarter alternative to just scheduling a `kinit -R` cronjob.

The same package comes with a `k5start` tool which works in a very similar way, but can also acquire new tickets from a *keytab* – if you're allowed to save your password on disk, in Kerberos it's usually done by creating a "keytab" file which contains a hashed form of your password and can be used with `kinit` (or k5start).

User keytabs can be created using `ktutil`. (It's the same kind of keytab as in /etc/krb5.keytab, except it holds your user credentials and not a service's, so it is *not* obtained using the same tools – the "msktutil" and "cern-get-keytab" tools do not apply.)

```
$ ktutil
ktutil:  addent -password -p foo@CERN.CH -k 0 -f
ktutil:  wkt foo.keytab
$ kinit -k -t foo.keytab
```

If you're allowed to use a user keytab, recent versions of MIT Krb5 can use it directly – all you need is to set the `KRB5_CLIENT_KTNAME` environment variable to the keytab path, and GSSAPI-using programs will automatically obtain or refresh tickets as necessary – without even needing to use `kinit` nor `k5start`.